# Problemas con npm dentro de proyecto docker

Tags: reactjs, npm, docker-compose

me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto docker, que contiene un app tipo CRUD..
Recientemente actualice el repositorio en github, eliminé mi repositorio local y clone la versión de github para comprobar que todo funciona correctamente y así lo hace.. El problema viene en el siguiente punto, realizo un branch para trabajar sobre modificaciones a la app sin afectar su código original y en ese punto debo de instalar nuevas librerias, cuando ejecuto el comando

```
npm i
```

me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/node_modules/core-js-pure' -> '/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/node_modules/.core-js-pure-Fn5dQBuO'

Estuve informándome acerca del error y en la gran mayoría de los casos el problema se resuelve eliminando la carpeta `node_modules` y reinstalando la misma con `npm i`. En mi caso esa solución no tuvo éxito. Soy nuevo y agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Ese error pasaba mucho antes con versiones de npm viejas, tienes npm actualizado?

Comment: Por favor ve a [edit] tu pregunta e indica cómo intentaste eliminar la carpeta node_modules dentro del contenedor docker; "no tuvo éxito" es una mala descripción de cualquier cosa.

Comment: tu error trata de decirte que el archivo que trata de escribir ya existe, en tu caso puedes intentar borrar /mnt/c/Users/Usuario/node_modules/core-js-pure que es donde marca el problema.